# Como fazer um placar em PHP ou JS?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Vi muitas perguntas parecidas porem nenhumas me atendeu, não gostaria de usar Ajax pois como é um exercício o professor pediu apenas JS,HTML e PHP.

Fiz um mini game de Quiz, está tudo funcionando certinho porem não consegui fazer o placar. Cheguei a criar uma SESSION em PHP como placar mas não consegui atualizar ela conforme a resposta do usuário.

```html
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE & ~ E_DEPRECATED);
require_once "../config.php";
$i = $_SESSION["id_quests"];
$g = $_SESSION["guia"];

$con = new PDO(SERVIDOR, USUARIO, SENHA);
$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `quiz` WHERE id=$i;");
$sql->execute();
$r = $sql->fetchObject();

if($r == true){
  $g++;
  $_SESSION["guia"] = $g;
  $i++;
  $_SESSION["id_quests"] = $i;      
}
if($r == false){
  if($_SESSION["num_quest"] == $g){
    header("location:resultado.php");
  }else{
    $i++;
    $_SESSION["id_quests"] = $i;
    echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='0;URL=quiz.php'>";
} };

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
<head>
    <title>Quiz - <?php print $g; ?></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<style>

.overlay {
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 62px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
</style>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand">Quiz</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a>Questao Numero <?php print $g; ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="inicio.php">Desistir</a></li>
      <li><a>Pontuação : <?php print $_SESSION["placar"]; ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a><font color="green">Acertou <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i></font></a><br>
    <font style="font-size: 42px;"><span>Proxima pergunta em </span><span id="hora"></span></font>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myNav2" class="overlay">
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a><font color="red">Errou <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></font></a>
    <font style="font-size: 42px;"><span>Proxima pergunta em </span><span id="hora2"></span></font>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<br><br><br>
    <h1><?=$r->pergunta?></h1>
<br><br><br>
    <form>
        <a id="a" onclick="resultado('a')" class="btn btn-default btn-block"><?=$r->a?></a><br>
        <a id="b" onclick="resultado('b')" class="btn btn-default btn-block"><?=$r->b?></a><br>
        <a id="c" onclick="resultado('c')" class="btn btn-default btn-block"><?=$r->c?></a><br>
        <a id="d" onclick="resultado('d')" class="btn btn-default btn-block"><?=$r->d?></a><br>
        <a id="e" onclick="resultado('e')" class="btn btn-default btn-block"><?=$r->e?></a>
    </form>

</div>
</body>
<script>
certa = "<?php print $r->certa; ?>";

function resultado(alternativa){
    if(certa == alternativa){
    $('#'+alternativa).attr("class", "btn btn-success btn-block");
    $('#a').attr("onclick", "");
    $('#b').attr("onclick", "");
    $('#c').attr("onclick", "");
    $('#d').attr("onclick", "");
    $('#e').attr("onclick", "");
    window.setTimeout(openNav,1000);
    }else{
    $('#'+alternativa).attr("class", "btn btn-danger btn-block");
    $('#'+certa).attr("class", "btn btn-success btn-block");
    $('#a').attr("onclick", "");
    $('#b').attr("onclick", "");
    $('#c').attr("onclick", "");
    $('#d').attr("onclick", "");
    $('#e').attr("onclick", "");
    window.setTimeout(openNav2,1000);
    }
}

function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
    relogio();
}

function openNav2() {
    document.getElementById("myNav2").style.height = "100%";
    relogio();
}

var segundo = 5;
 function relogio() {             

if(segundo > 0 ){segundo--;}; 
 document.getElementById('hora').innerHTML = segundo;
 document.getElementById('hora2').innerHTML = segundo;
if(segundo == 0){location.reload();}; 
 setTimeout("relogio()",1000); 
 }


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Não é possível atualizar os valores de variáveis, *sessions* etc com PHP após o processamento/carregamento da página. Mas você pode trabalhar com `Cookies`, eles funcionam tanto com PHP quanto JS

Comment: Eu não consigo nem fazer um placar em js e depois atribuir o resultado para a session php ?

Comment: Não. O PHP (Hypertext Preprocessor) é uma linguagem pré processada, após a página ser carregada, você só poderá alterar/criar/remover valores do PHP, com uma nova requisição, mas você pode utilizar https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie **e** http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.cookies.php ou ainda trabalhar com `localStorage` (com JavaScript)

Comment: Teria como chamar uma função PHP através do JS?

Comment: Não! Como mencionei anteriormente: após a página ser carregada **não** é possível trabalhar/utilizar o PHP, exceto em uma nova requisição (via Ajax, por exemplo).

Comment: Ok amigo muito obrigado, consegui fazendo outra outra pagina cahmada "placar.php" que quando o usuário acerta eu redireciono para essa pagina e então redireciona de volta para quiz.php.